# Scheduled change for cart price rule activation

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, coupon-codes, schedule

When a scheduled change is set for a cart price rule activation, it doesn't work on the storefront within the set time frame, namely, when I put the coupon code, it shows a message that a coupon code is invalid

given that:

1. It happens only for activation scheduled change (it does work properly for inactivation)
2. The rule is showing as active on the admin side, even though it's not working on the storefront or at least it considers the coupon code is invalid
3. It happens only for cart price rules with specific coupon code option, namely, it works for automated cart price rules with no coupon codes

Anyone has encountered any similar issue before?